# Enable error in tools developer of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Every day it run good, But today I can't show the error in Developer Tools of Chrome. In image below you can see, at the top of the right have 1 error. But it do not show in the screen. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing Chrome and re-opening it?

Comment: I has been try, but it is the same?

Comment: try keeping the options to default and reset it back to errors only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right of the top Developer Tools, click button setting, In the setting screen, scroll to the bottom. You can see button "Restore  defaults and reload".
Click on it.

[image]